# Calculate CI for chi-squared of the Friedman test in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, friedman-test

I have a dataset (not normal distribution) with repeated measures over time. As such I was planning to use the Friedman.test in R:

```
friedman.test(dash ~ time | nr)
```

this gave:

> Friedman rank sum test
>
> data: dash and time and nr Friedman chi-squared = 105.26, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16

To calculate the CI of the chi-squared I tried the following:

```
friedman_boot <- function(data, indices) {
  return(friedman.test(dash ~ time | nr, data = data_t[indices, ])$statistic)
}

boot_results <- boot(data = data_t, statistic = friedman_boot, R = 1000)

boot_ci <- boot.ci(boot.out = boot_results, type = "perc", conf = 0.95)

boot_ci
```

which gave:

```
boot_results <- boot(data = data_t, statistic = friedman_boot, R = 1000) 

Error in friedman.test.default(mf[[1L]], mf[[2L]], mf[[3L]]) : not an unreplicated complete block design
```

I do not quite understand why this happens. Does anyone have another way to calculate CI for the test statistic?

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. You calculate confidence intervals for *unknown parameters* of the population or process. A test statistic is a sample statistic, not a population/process parameter. What is the underlying problem you were trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to calculate the CI for the Friedman statistic, particularly given the very small *p*-value, but here's a way to proceed if you do.

The problem is that the `friedman.test()` function, according to its R help page, requires "exactly one observation in [outcome] `y` for each combination of levels of groups and blocks," where the "group" is `time` in your case and "blocks" are your `nr` values. Your resampling leads to repeated `nr` values in the same group, violating that requirement.

You also don't seem to be resampling by block/`nr`, which would be more consistent with the original sampling: a set of individuals each followed over all time values. To do that, start by reshaping your data into wide format so that you select all observations for each `nr` value together. The [`tidyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tidyr) `nest()` function can simplify that. After you've taken a bootstrap re-sample from the wide format, adjust the `nr` values so that there are no duplicates (to get around the warning from `friedman.test()`) and `unnest()` to long format for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution presented by @EdM is the correct approach to apply bootstrap for Friedman's test.

You may be interested in Kendall's *W* which is used as an effect size statistic for Friedman's test, and is a standardized version of the *chi*-square statistic from that test.

In R, one implementation is in the *DescTools* package (`KendallW()`). And I have a version which implements the confidence interval by bootstrap in the *rcompanion* package (`kendallW()`).

For each of these, the input is passed to the function as a table, e.g. by

```
 XT = xtabs(dash ~ time | nr, data = data_t)
```

If you conduct the bootstrap yourself, you might want to work with data in this table format.  The native `friedman.test()` function can also handle data in this format, so it should be easy to pass the bootstrap data to this function (without converting it back to long format).